# What is the distance formula MongoDB uses for a $near query?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, distance

I've tried looking through mongodb's source code, but I can't figure out how they calculate the $near results for distance. I need to then re-write their method in javascript so I can display the distance.

note: I know using an aggregate call, I can get the returned distance, but in my case I can't use an aggregate.

Comment: what do you exactly want? query related to distance or how it will be in javascript??

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use an aggregation? That's a very strange restriction, especially because `$near` won't work if you grow into a sharded cluster! Can you use the [`geoNear` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear)?

If you absolutely must compute the distance between two points on a sphere, I'd suggest just using a standard formula like the ones from the article on [distance on spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance). The simple(r) formulas for a perfect sphere are accurate within 1% for the Earth, which is a bit squished and obviously not perfectly smooth.